# How to cast variables in T-SQL for bulk insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The following code gives an error (its part of a T-SQL stored procedure):

```
-- Bulk insert data from the .csv file into the staging table.
DECLARE @CSVfile nvarchar(255);
SET @CSVfile = N'T:\x.csv';
BULK INSERT [dbo].[TStagingTable]
-- FROM N'T:\x.csv' -- This line works
FROM @CSVfile -- This line will not work
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
FIRSTROW = 2    
)
```

The error is:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
```

If I replace:

```
FROM @CSVfile
```

with:

```
FROM 'T:\x.csv'
```

... then it works nicely.

Comment: I find it astonishing that the `BULK INSERT` syntax of SQL Server fails to accept an expression that evaluates to an SQL string following the keyword `FROM`. How random.

Comment: And that's why PostgreSQL is so nice: weirdly obtuse corner case like this just get *fixed*, not left there to fester.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As I know only literal string is required in the from. In that case you have to write a dynamic query to use bulk insert

```
declare @q nvarchar(MAX);
set @q=
    'BULK INSERT [TStagingTable]
    FROM '+char(39)+@CSVfile+char(39)+'
    WITH
    (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
    FIRSTROW = 1  
    )'
exec(@q)
```

Comment: Brilliant, this worked with just a few modifications. It didn't seem to work if I used any double quotes in the query at all, your solution is pretty much perfect.

Comment: What about SQL Injection?

Comment: All of the answers seem to ignore SQL Injection.  Is there no way to parameterise the dynamic SQL for bulk insert?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried with dynamic SQL?

```
SET @SQL = "BULK INSERT TmpStList FROM '"+@PathFileName+"' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '"",""') "
```

and then

```
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Ref.: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-bulk-insert-to-load-a-text-file

Comment: What about SQL Injection?

Comment: Exactly.  Surely there is a way to do this using sp_ExecuteSQL with parameters?

Answer (score 2):

you have to engage in string building & then calling EXEC() or sp_executesql  [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) 
has an example:

```
DECLARE @bulk_cmd varchar(1000)
SET @bulk_cmd = 'BULK INSERT AdventureWorks2008R2.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
FROM ''<drive>:\<path>\<filename>'' 
WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+''')'
EXEC(@bulk_cmd)
```

Comment: What about SQL Injection?

Answer (score 1):

A string literal is required.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

You could use dynamic sql to generate the string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time the variable i'm looking for in a file name is the date, and this one works perfectly for bulk inserting files with date, for use such as in a daily job. Change as per your need, date format, table name, file path, file name and delimiters.

```
    DECLARE @DT VARCHAR (10)
    DECLARE @INSERT VARCHAR (1000)
    SET @DT = (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()-1,120))
    SET @INSERT = 'BULK INSERT dbo.table FROM ''C:\FOLDER\FILE'+@DT+'.txt'''+' WITH  (FIRSTROW=2, FIELDTERMINATOR=''\t'', ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'')'
    EXEC (@INSERT);
```

Comment: What about SQL Injection?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try `FROM ' + @CSVfile + '`

Comment: See "[answer]" and [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.