# BULK INSERT with variable file name

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to bulk insert into Db using sql server 2005

Below is the code.

```
declare @path varchar(500) 
set @path = 'E:\Support\test.csv'; 

Create table #mytable( name varchar(max), class varchar(max), roll varchar(max) )

BULK INSERT #mytable FROM @path <-- Error line
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' ); 
Go 
select * from #mytable
drop table #mytable
```

**Problem**: issue is that my file path is dynamic and comes from a variable instead of hard coding which is not working
If i change the error line to below it works

```
 BULK INSERT #mytable FROM 'E:\Support\test.csv';
```

Please advise how to fix this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cast variables in T-SQL for bulk insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019041/how-to-cast-variables-in-t-sql-for-bulk-insert)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try to use Dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'BULK INSERT #mytable FROM ''' + @path + ''' WITH ...
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: For future users, notice that there are 3 quotes before/after the variable. It took me a while to make it work because I was only adding 2

Comment: Shoule be `'BULK INSERT #mytable FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@path, '''') + ' WITH ...` to correctly escape the file name.

Answer (score 12):

```
DECLARE @path varchar(50) = 'D:\ARQUIVOS_CARGAS\CABOS\FILE.prn'
DECLARE @SQL_BULK VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL_BULK = 'BULK INSERT #TAB FROM ''' + @path + ''' WITH
        (
        CODEPAGE = ''ACP'',
        FIRSTROW = 1,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ''tab'',
        ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a'',
        KEEPNULLS
        )'

EXEC (@SQL_BULK)
```