# How to BULK INSERT files that change name every day?

Tags: sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I have a folder that is static with a daily txt file that goes into the folder. The file name is the date. If the file name has the same name every day, everything works. Is there a way I can have my script pull any txt file in the folder? (Note, file comes in, get's processed and then I have an automatic transfer that moves the file after it has been inserted to a processed folder). So there will only be one file at a time in the folder. I hope that makes sense.

Here is the script for the bulk insert:

```
Bulk Insert Mydata.dbo.cust_adj 
From 'C:\MyData\FlatFiles\UnprocessedAdjReport\importformat.txt' 
With 
(
FieldTerminator= '|', 
Rowterminator= '\n' 
) 
Go
```

(I've got this saved as a stored procedure btw)

So "importformat" is just the name I used while setting up my scripts, going forward it will be in `bb-yyyy-mmdd-hhmmnnnn.txt`, as soon as the file is inserted, I move the file from the unprocessed folder to the processed folder. There will only be the one file each day.

If anyone has any advice or assistance with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You should add the relevent tags for the database system you are using. Otherwise the right people will probably not see your question.

Comment: Ok, I added SQL Server 2008 as a tag. It's actually in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Comment: You need to build the file name dynamically as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547393/bulk-insert-with-variable-file-name). But personally I would do it outside the database using a small script in PowerShell or some other convenient language: TSQL is really weak for working with the file system and parsing/generating text.

Answer (score 0):

See the link it may be what you are looking for:

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-extract-filename-from-path-using-sql-functions.aspx

Or

http://sqljourney.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/get-list-of-files-from-a-windows-directory-to-sql-server/

Or maybe

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38850/An-Easy-Way-to-Get-a-File-Name-or-a-File-Extension

HTH