# SQL Bulk Insert in a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying run BULK INSERT in a loop. Loop through each file in some directory ends with no of particular file. Below is my solution

```
DECLARE @startFlag INT
DECLARE @endFlag INT
DECLARE @fileName varchar(50)
SET @startFlag = 1
SET @endFlag = 10
WHILE (@startFlag <= @endFlag)
BEGIN
    SET @fileName = 'c:\path to file\filename_' + cast(@startFlag as varchar) + '.csv'
    BULK
    INSERT dbo.Intraday
    FROM @fileName
    WITH
    (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
    SET @startFlag = @startFlag + 1
END
GO
```

but seems don't work. Is there anything I've overlooked or another missing stuff I can fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have files like this `c:\path to file\filename_1.csv' `

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is what
SET @fileName = 'c:\path to file\filename_' + cast(@startFlag as varchar) + '.csv'
does.

Comment: Not sure what is your issue here ,unless you have some MVCE..Here are some answers which might help for your question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547393/bulk-insert-with-variable-file-name

Comment: Please expand on "but seems don't work" in your question post

Comment: @TheGameiswar Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use variables or expressions all the places you might like in TSQL.  You'll have to use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @fileName nvarchar(2000) = 'foo.csv'
SET @fileName = 'foo'
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
BULK
INSERT dbo.Intraday
FROM '''+@fileName+'''
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'',
ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
)';

exec (@sql);
```

Comment: Just out of interest, could he not use QUOTENAME() for @FileName, Delimiter & terminator and so use non dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 0):

you can not use veritable name after From. you have to provide the name of file after from clause not variable. so you need to make complete bulk insert statement dynamically. please refer below sample code -

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)    
DECLARE @fileName varchar(50)
set @fileName ='C:\Input.txt' 

set  @sql = 'BULK
    INSERT dbo.Intraday
    FROM ''' + @fileName + '''
    WITH
    (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'',
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
    )'

exec(@sql)
```