# Loading Multiple CSV files into Multiple tables in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, database, csv

I have stocks data as .CSV (total 500 CSVs). My objective is to create a database with multiple tables named as 'A', 'B' where A & B refer to two different stocks. 
I've a table already loaded in database which contains a column with all 500 symbols.

I want to iterate over each row such that I can read CSV and create a table for that stock  in my database. For example if the first row in the symbols table is 'A' then I want to create a table in my database named A by reading a csv file which would be named  as '/path/A.csv'

All the tables have same structure. There are four columns "Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume"

I've created a table for one stock. For example in case of stock A by using following code

```
create table A(
  [Date] datetime2(7) NOT NULL,
  [Open] float NULL,
  High float NULL,
  Low float NULL,
  [close] float NULL,
  Volume float NULL
  )
  BULK INSERT A
    FROM 'D:\ASX\A.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row

    TABLOCK
    )
```

Since I can not manually change the name from A to B and to C till it reaches 500 therefore I would like to know how can I iterate 500 rows from my symbols table such that for each iteration my above code changes from A to B to C and so on.

Comment: Do you have the list of list of symbols or is derived only from the files in the directory? It seems to be it would be better to add a symbol column and import all the files into a single table. That single entity is more appropriate for a relational database.

Comment: I have a another table named symbols containing a single column named Ticker with 500 rows, where each row is a Ticker. For example the first row would be named as 'A'.

Comment: No. do not create a table per stock. Create one table with an additional column containing the stock code

Comment: I have separate CSV's for each stock so even if I create one data table with an additional column of stock code I need to run a loop while reading CSV. How would I do that?

Comment: @f_hashim, I added an example of the normalized table design to my answer.

Comment: If you have 500 CSV's you will need a while loop regardless of how you store it. Here's one way to import every file in a folder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076309/import-multiple-csv-files-to-sql-server-from-a-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is one method to create and import data for each ticker symbol in your symbols table with your existing design.

```
DECLARE @Path nvarchar(255) = 'D:\ASX';
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = (SELECT N'
CREATE TABLE dbo.' + QUOTENAME(ticker) + N'(
  [Date] datetime2(7) NOT NULL,
  [Open] float NULL,
  High float NULL,
  Low float NULL,
  [close] float NULL,
  Volume float NULL
  );
BULK INSERT ' + QUOTENAME(ticker) + N'
    FROM ''' + @Path + N'\' + ticker + N'.csv''
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
    );'
FROM dbo.symbols
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.',N'nvarchar(MAX)');
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
GO
```

I suggest you reconsider this design and create a single table with a ticker symbol column and import all files into a single table. Below is an example of this method:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.all_tickers(
  ticker_symbol varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  [Date] datetime2(7) NOT NULL,
  [Open] float NULL,
  High float NULL,
  Low float NULL,
  [close] float NULL,
  Volume float NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ticker_symbol, [Date])
);
GO

DECLARE @Path nvarchar(255) = 'D:\ASX';
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
CREATE TABLE #ticker_staging(
  [Date] datetime2(7) NOT NULL,
  [Open] float NULL,
  High float NULL,
  Low float NULL,
  [close] float NULL,
  Volume float NULL
  );

SET @SQL = (SELECT N'
TRUNCATE TABLE #ticker_staging;
BULK INSERT #ticker_staging
    FROM ''' + @Path + N'\' + ticker + N'.csv''
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
    );
INSERT INTO dbo.all_tickers WITH (TABLOCKX)(
  ticker_symbol,
  [Date],
  [Open],
  High,
  Low,
  [close],
  Volume
) 
SELECT
  ''' + ticker + N''',
  [Date],
  [Open],
  High,
  Low,
  [close],
  Volume
FROM #ticker_staging;'
FROM dbo.symbols
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.',N'nvarchar(MAX)');
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
GO
```

Comment: To create one single table do i need to have a single CSV containing all the symbols data with an additional column or a single table can be achieved by having data in multiple CSVs?

Comment: @f_hashim, no need for a single, although that would be desirable to avoid the dynamic SQL. I added an example for the single target table and multiple source files.

Comment: Appreciated. I am going through the your example to build a better understanding and I believe a single table would be more feasible.