# Import Flat File in same table not in new table

Tags: sql-server, flat-file

I have **40 CSV** files to import on one table, while importing it always creates a new table against each CSV. I am stuck on what to do and is any query for it to import all data from CSV and dump it in one table.

[image]

I try below query as well

```
BULK INSERT dbo.OBD_dataset4
FROM 'C:\Users\abc\Downloads\OBD_data\OBD_data\OBD_dataset5.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = ' ',   
    TABLOCK,
    CODEPAGE = 'ACP'
);
```

I am using SQL Server Management Studio V17.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import Multiple CSV Files to SQL Server from a Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076309/import-multiple-csv-files-to-sql-server-from-a-folder)

Comment: not resolve my query

Comment: The import wizard may be unhelpful and require a new table but, as you've seen, the `BULK INSERT` statement doesn't have that issue. Just execute it multiple times - with a different source path each time.