# How to insert data from multiple CSV files into one single table in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, csv

I am trying to insert data from multiple CSV files from a single folder to a single table.

I can do bulinsert for 1 file using the following code:

```
USE [dbname]
GO
BULK INSERT tablename
FROM 'path to csv files'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2, -- as 1st one is header
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
)
GO
```

Comment: What did you try? What is working, and what is not?

Comment: What is your SQL Server version (`SELECT @@VERSION;`)?

Comment: Why not to use SSIS for the task?

Comment: This should be a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076309/import-multiple-csv-files-to-sql-server-from-a-folder

Comment: I have tried the above code for one file and it is working. I have close to 1000 files for one table. My SQL server version is 2019 15.0.

Comment: Use an ETL tool to loop through the files, @RushanArshad . Or, even, use Powershell or something. SQL is the *wrong* tool to loop through the files here.

Comment: Thank you. If I choose to keep SQL as my database, any ETL tool you can recommend to insert the data from CSV files to a table?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would say is I personally wouldn't do this in T-SQL, I'd use something a bit better suited to the task, the [SSIS Multiple flat file connection manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/connection-manager/multiple-flat-files-connection-manager?view=sql-server-ver16) for example. This is possible in T-SQL but it is not the most robust approach and has limitation (such as the directories that can even be accessed).

```
-- Set the directory to check for files
DECLARE @Directory NVARCHAR(200) = N'C:\Your File Location\';

-- Create a table variable to store the files output from xp_dirtree
DECLARE @Files TABLE (FileName NVARCHAR(255), Depth INT, IsFile BIT);

-- Get the files from the folder
INSERT @Files(FileName, Depth, IsFile)
EXECUTE master..xp_dirtree @Directory, 1, 1;

--select the filenames and use STRING_AGG to combine into a single string to execute
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    (  SELECT   STRING_AGG(CONCAT('BULK INSERT YourTableName FROM ''', 
                              CONCAT(@Directory, f.FileName), '''  
                            WITH (
                                FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
                                ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
                                FIRSTROW = 1  
                            )'), ';' + CHAR(10))
        FROM    @Files AS f
        WHERE   f.IsFile = 1
        AND     f.FileName LIKE '%.csv'-- Optionally limit files
    ); 

PRINT @SQL;
-- Uncomment below line once you're happy with the SQL Printed
--EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Or if you want a bit more control over error handling, you could use a cursor to iterate the files:

```
-- Set the directory to check for files
DECLARE @Directory NVARCHAR(200) = N'C:\Import Location\';

-- Create a table variable to store the files output from xp_dirtree
DECLARE @Files TABLE (FileName NVARCHAR(255), Depth INT, IsFile BIT);

-- Get the files from the folder
INSERT @Files(FileName, Depth, IsFile)
EXECUTE master..xp_dirtree @Directory, 1, 1;

--declare a cursor to loop through the files, filtered for csv
DECLARE FileCursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY 
FOR
SELECT  FilePath = CONCAT(@Directory, f.FileName)
FROM    @Files AS f
WHERE   f.IsFile = 1
AND     f.FileName LIKE '%.csv'; -- Optionally limit files

OPEN FileCursor;
DECLARE @FilePath NVARCHAR(255);
FETCH FROM FileCursor INTO @FilePath;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @FilePath;
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        CONCAT('BULK INSERT YourTableName FROM ''', @FilePath, '''  
                WITH (
                    FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
                    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
                    FIRSTROW = 1  
                )');
    BEGIN TRY
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL; 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- Do something to handle errors
    END CATCH 
    FETCH NEXT FROM FileCursor INTO @FilePath; 
END


CLOSE FileCursor;
DEALLOCATE FileCursor;
```

As I say though, SSIS or another dedicated ETL tool is a better choice.

Comment: I would mention `xp_dirtree` is an undocumented system extended stored proc so it may change or be removed without notice in a future SQL Server version or CU.