# Bulk Insert: Can the FROM <filepath> be paramertized?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to develop an app that can handle bulk inserts of files into a given table.  The path of the files can vary so I wanted to develop a stored proc that I can call and pass in the path.

The following works well

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[tblUTAClockExport]
FROM '\\warhawk\C$\test\clock_export_20180922.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' );
```

... but I can't replace the path with a parameter.  This fails:

```
declare @fname as varchar(200);
set @fname = '\\warhawk\C$\test\clock_export_20180922.csv';
BULK INSERT [dbo].[tblUTAClockExport]
FROM @fname
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' );
```

Any suggestions for a work around?

Comment: What error message do you get?  Does that answer your question?  Did you read the manual for `BULK INSERT`?

Comment: Use dynamic SQL

Comment: The documentation for [`BULK INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) shows the argument as `FROM 'data_file' `. It must be quoted string, not a variable or expression. Dynamic SQL is an alternative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cast variables in T-SQL for bulk insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019041/how-to-cast-variables-in-t-sql-for-bulk-insert)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create string with your command and then execute it using EXEC:

```
declare @fname as varchar(200);
declare @command as varchar(max);

set @fname = '\\warhawk\C$\test\clock_export_20180922.csv';

set @command = 'BULK INSERT [dbo].[tblUTAClockExport]'
                +' FROM '+char(39)+@fname+char(39)
                +' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '+char(39)+','+char(39)+' );'
EXEC(@command)
```