# BULK INSERT from variable Date Filename - ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to do an insert of a text file that contain datetime in filename.

```
declare @V_SQL varchar(100)
set @V_SQL = (select REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,getdate()-1,106), ' ',''), ',',''))
BULK INSERT [dbo].[test] FROM '"E:\test_"+ @V_SQL +".txt"'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
)
GO
```

When I run the above I get following message - `BULK INSERT [dbo].[test] FROM '"E:\test_"+ @V_SQL +".txt"'`

Comment: `FROM` only accepts a literal, not an expression (and your syntax isn't correct for that anyway). If you want a variable file name, you'll have to build the whole `BULK INSERT` statement dynamically (`REPLACE('BULK INSERT [dbo].[test] FROM $f WITH...', '$f', QUOTENAME('E:\test_' + @V_SQL + '.txt', ''''))`) and `EXEC` it.

Comment: I've tried like:. but with delimiter is |. It seems not to work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cast variables in T-SQL for bulk insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019041/how-to-cast-variables-in-t-sql-for-bulk-insert)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put a variable or an expression there. You'll need to use dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'BULK INSERT dbo.test FROM '''
  + 'c:\test_' 
  + REPLACE(CONVERT(char(11), DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()), 13),' ','') 
  + ''' WITH 
     (
       FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'',
       ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a''
     );';

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

I strongly recommend:

- [not using shorthand for date operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) (e.g. `GETDATE()-1`)
- [always declaring lengths for variable data types like `varchar`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: Yes. It's work. Thanks. If you have any basic and advance tutorials for Dynamic SQL. Pls send me.

Comment: @HungNguyen I have a good example of [how to use dynamic SQL effectively here](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/), and a debugging tip [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/), but you should also be concerned about SQL injection (see [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/) and [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/)).

Comment: I really appreciate this. Thanks